# Function for list elements concatenation?

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x

I want to create a function which concatenates all the strings within a list and returns the resulting string. I tried something like this

```
def join_strings(x):
    for i in x:
        word = x[x.index(i)] + x[x.index(i) + 1]
    return word
#set any list with strings and name it n.
print join_strings(n)
```

but it doesn't work and I can't figure out why. Any solution to the problem or fix of my thought? I thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For real work, use `''.join(x)`.

The problem with your code is that you are changing `word` each iteration, without keeping previous strings.
try:

```
def join_strings(x):
    word = ''
    for i in x:
        word += i
    return word
```

This is an example of a general pattern of using an *accumulator*. Something that keeps the information and is updated accross different loops/recursive calls. This method will work almost as is (except the `word=''` part) for joining lists and tuples and more, or summing anything - actually, it is close to be reimplementation of the `sum` built in function. A closer one will be:

```
def sum(iterable, s=0):
    acc = s
    for t in iterable:
        acc += s
    return acc
```

Of course, for strings you can achieve the same effect using `''.join(x)`, and in general (numbers, lists, etc.) you can use the `sum` function. an even more general case would be to replace `+=` with a general operation:

```
from operator import add
def reduce(iterable, s=0, op=add):
    acc = s
    for t in iterable:
        acc = op(w, s)
    return acc
```

Comment: It would be so silly if you actually did that in python when you can just use the build in `join` method.

Comment: @IonutHulub it depends, if you want to join strings or you want to learn how it can be done. The OP asked what is the problem in his code.

Comment: @IonutHulub this answers the question though, however it would be nice to suggest `''.join` at the end for completeness

Comment: yessss. thank you! edit: new to python, havent learnt yet join so this is perfect for me!

Comment: @jamylak This does answer the question but it's not the right answer. OP should be thought about the built in function.

Comment: @IonutHulub  read this part of my last comment: *"nice to suggest `''.join` at the end for completeness"*

Comment: @user2460125: *use* join, now that you know how to do it yourself.

Comment: @jamylak It wouldn't "be nice" to suggest. It's the only right thing to do. Any other way of joining string in python is silly. Do you know how much faster the built in `join` method is compared to concatenating strings using the `+` operator? Not to mention that it's a lot faster to code.

Comment: @IonutHulub you bet jamylak knows that pretty well. I do too. But the OP encountered a different problem: not "how can I join strings" but "why is this code not working".

Comment: @IonutHulub OP is trying to learn how to program in Python, it's best to learn the manual way first so you understand how it works. If you look at the code given in the question, OP was having troubles with this and Elazar has illustrated how to fix that code

Comment: @jamylak i am on my second day on python and this was an exercise i encountered. i wanted a fix to my thought initially, but any more advanced (for my level) solution is really welcome!

Comment: @user2460125 use `''.join(x)`, also remember to accept this answer